# How to add onscroll event to a JavaScript InfoVis StackArea Chart

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, infovis

I seem to be having trouble arising from adding a scrollbar to my JavaScript Chart. The problem is my chart

infovis is 2400px, while the frame is 800. However, whenever I scroll right, the cursor becomes misaligned and trails (as though the x and y coordinates have become confused).

To give you a better idea, here is a link to the chart.

http://philogb.github.com/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/AreaChart/example1.html

My question is: how can I best rectify this problem? Should onscroll be called in the html div or css or .js file? Also, what do i use for the selected div? Would it be the center container holding the visualization, the overall window, or #vis (the visualization itself). I have attached a screenshot below for clarification.

Due to the animation and drilling down capabilities of the graph, this issue renders the graph unusable. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Also, here is a link to the open source API this is based on: http://philogb.github.com/jit/demos.html

Unfortunately the site will not allow me to post a screenshot.